# Creating an abstract function which takes different arguments depending on inheritor

Tags: c#, function, inheritance, abstract

I've stumbled upon a problem which I can't think of a good way of solving.

There are objects in my program which need to be reinitialized upon some event. The objects I need to reinitilize are sub classes of an abstract class.

And although it seems like a bad way of going ahead I decided to have an abstract reinitlize function in the abstract class and let all the subclasses implement the function. But now theres the problem that each sub class takes different arguments in their constructors.

The minimal example I have looks like the following:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Init(/* Some parameter */);
}

class SubA : Base
{
    public SubA(int a)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public override void Init(int a)
    {
        //do stuff with int
    }
}

class SubB : Base
{
    public SubB(string b)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public override void Init(string b)
    {
        //do stuff with string
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Base> stuff = new List<Base>()
        {
            new SubA(65),
            new SubB("B")
        };

        foreach (var s in stuff)
        {
            s.Init();
        }
    }
}`
```

I do believe this solution has a code smell to it, so any suggestion of avoiding this scenario is welcome. Please let me know if any additional information is needed to help me out.

Comment: You are _not_ overriding the `Init()` in your base class here.

Comment: @Sach, sorry I should have been more clear that this was what I was trying to accomplish. I've edited it now which hopefully is more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, solution is simple, just declare *specific* variables in private fields and use those fields in **paramaterless** `Init` method, something like this:

```
class SubA : Base
{
    private int _a;
    public SubA(int a)
    {
        _a = a;
        Init();
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        //do stuff with int _a
    }
}

class SubB : Base
{
    private string _b;
    public SubB(string b)
    {
        _b = b;
        Init();
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        //do stuff with string _b
    }
}
```

Also, you can make you abstract class interface instead, so classes implementing it will be able to inherit from other base classes as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is specifically what he's trying to do, though I thought that could be a solution as well.

Comment: Wow, of course this is the way to go. How did I not think of this.. Thank you.
And @n234, yes this is actually what I was trying to do, but English is not my mother's milk.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use an interface instead.

```
public interface IBase
{
    void Init();
}

public class SubA : IBase
{
    private int _a;
    public SubA(int a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        // do stuff with _a
    }
}

public class SubB : IBase
{
    private string _s;
    public SubB(string s)
    {
        _s = s;
    }
    public void Init()
    {
        // do stuff with _s
    }
}

public class SubC : IBase
{
    private int _a;
    private string _s;
    public SubC(int a, string s)
    {
        _a = a;
        _s = s;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        // do stuff with _a and _s
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IBase> stuff = new List<IBase>()
        {
            new SubA(65),
            new SubB("B"),
            new SubC(100, "Z"),
        };

        foreach (IBase sub in stuff)
        {
            sub.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I not be able to do the same thing with an abstract class? The issue I have with this solution is that it would get confusing if it were more parameters, all of which are sent in as objects.

Comment: Yes, and that's Michał Turczyn answer. I've now edited my answer to work in a similar fashion. The choice of using an abstract class vs an interface depends on your specific circumstances. For example, if all of the Sub classes have similar functionality, you could make a method in the base class that all the derived classes can use. Interfaces are better if the Sub classes are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

It's confusing why you would want to re-initialize a collection of items in a loop in a way that each item gets a new value. There are a bunch of issues with your code, but I will try to explain them, since your example doesn't compile.

First, if you want to call Init in the subclass `SubA` you have to implement it in the `SubA` like this.

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract void Init()
}

class SubA : Base
{
    public SubA(int a)
    {
        this.Init();
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void Init(int a)
    {
        //do stuff with int
    }
}
```

if you want to call init without overriding it, then the abstract base class needs to implement it like this

```
abstract class Base
{
    public void Init()
    {
        //do stuff in the implementation by the abstract class
    }
}

class SubA : Base
{
    public SubA(int a)
    {
        this.Init();
    }

    public void Init(int a)
    {
        //do stuff with int
    }
}
```

It seems like what you want is to be able to re-init any subclass of `Base`, with the option to for the sub classes to perform custom initialization.

If you want them to re-init to their original state, you could store their original state in the instance, and restore is with Init() that is overridden.

```
class Foo : Base
{
    private int _iOrig;
    private string _sOrig;

    public int i { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }

    public Foo(int i, string s)
    {
        this.i = i;
        this._iOrig = i;
        this.s = s;
        this._sOrig = s;
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        this.i = _iOrig;
        this.s = _sOrig;
    }
}
```

You might even consider using an interface if everything is going to to be abstract.

If instead you want to reinitialize them using outside data, you could loop through them and check what type they are, and call their own `Init` method, this means that `Base` doesn't need to have a `abstract Init()`, and the sub classes can implement whatever they want. (this doesn't seem to be what you want though).

This could be done in the loop using a cast check.

```
private void InitAll(IEnumerable<Base> collection)
{   

    foreach(Base b in collection)
    {
        var sa = b as SubA;
        if(sa != null)
        {
            sa.Init(getInt());
            continue;
        }

        var sb = b as SubB;
        if (sb != null)
        {
            sb.Init(getString());
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```